# Elasticsearch matching words

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have a problem. I want my query to match mysql with mysql!, mysql(, *mysql ... in other words I want my query result to show only these values which have just word "mysql" OR word "mysql" and special characters around this word.
For example query should get - mysql, mysql*, #mysql, mysql$. But not "mysql and R" or "mysql mysql".

I tried this query for matching, but I keep getting query malformed, no field after start_object, so not sure what to do. 
Also wanted to ask maybe there are other option to perform the same task ?

```
POST skills/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "match": {
                   "skillname": "mysql"
                }
           },
           "filter": {
                "type":"pattern_capture",
                "patterns":["mysql([@#]\\w+)"],
                "preserve_original": true
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my question. So basically I want from search to get only these values which have only single word mysql or word mysql with special characters around them. I hope I was able to explain it.

Comment: It seems your regex should be `"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*mysql[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*"`.

Comment: Can you post your mappings? It's quite unclear because for different kind of fields we can have different behavior.